Integrate range lock into file system
I’m working on an implementation of concurrent range lock. It provides 2 methods:
Lock: locks a range [start, end] if it is not existed or overlapped
 Unlock: unlock a range 
How can I integrate this implementation into filesystems like Ext4 for benchmakring purposes? Or could you suggest any other way to create a realistic workload for my implementation?
I imagine that I would have to modify the source code of filesystem so that it would call my implementation and then use benchmarking tools like fio or filebench to create I/O workloads.

Are you trying to replace the existing fcntl(2) locks which are filesystem agnostic and have range locking support?

Imagine two users reading same file, one from start to end and the other from end to start. Obviously two ends would be locked first but then both would await the other to release the lock before releasig their own locks. How would you solve this problem if both users are from different threads and do not know each other? Deadlocks are a problem for this maybe?
